# Where did the Greek consonant cluster "ps" come from

Tags: greek, indo-european, alphabets, writing, consonant-clusters

Where did the Greek consonant cluster "ps" come from? I tried finding resources to track down this fun-sounding consonant cluster but came with no information. I was thinking about a voicing change and fusion in the Afro-asiatic consonants b and z (As in Arabic biz'r - toasted pumpkin seed) from a Phoenician loanword of something, but that is unlikely for me. If it wasn't Phoenician loanwords, then how did the consonants p and s form together in the languages evolution?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Most often it just came from a labial consonant before /s/, same as in Latin.

Comment: Greek had letters for the clusters /ks/ and /ps/ (the case of */ts/ is more complicated) because the clusters were so common. A lot of Greek suffixes started with /s/, and a lot of the roots and stems they were added to ended with stops, so whenever /p/, /ph/, or /b/ wound up before an /s/, it was neutralized to PSI. Similar for /k/, /kh/, and /g/ neutralizing to XI. Just an abbreviation that caught on, really, like the Umlaut in German developing from a raised "e".

Comment: It's an interesting and good question, but Afroasiatic connection you seem to be suggesting is impossible. I suggest you add the indo-european tag and remove at least arabic (Early Greek had word-initial /ps/, /pt/ long before, and by long I mean at least 1000y, before Arabic was a language in its own right). Did you check Allen's _Vox Graeca_? The related πτερόν, πέτομαι (found already in Od.) immediately suggest the IE ablaut, but I cannot remember a similar vowel intrusion into words starting with the ψ.

Comment: @jlawler Greek has psi and ksi not because those clusters are especially common (they aren't), but because they're the only consonant clusters that can occur word-finally.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Well, there is -λς (though it's rare), and many dialects had -νς. Anyway I'm not sure that explains *why* Greek uses those letters -- they could just as easily have done without them, and did in early versions of the alphabet.

Comment: it should be about the symbolic value, *(o)ps* "face, head", *psykhe* "breath" can both mean person (via *soul, life* from *breath*; see also *head-count*) and it looks like a mannequin if you will. Imaginably there was a phase between logographs, syllabaries and alphabetization where logographics were still practiced. In that sense it's effectively Sumerian SAG ("head") simplified. There can be no doubt about it. Other characters may have different stories, but writing itself is not a typical topic for Linguistics, or it would be called kappalistics (ha!)

Comment: @Cairnarvon not sure what you are saying, Greek has psi and ksi because word endings (relatively) rare? Correlation is not causation, though you might have a point if it's due to aesthetic reasons, as they say, sometimes less is more.

Answer (score 9):

It's important to note that whilst Greek does spell /ps/ with a single letter, it does not represent a single phoneme, but a sequence of two.

In native vocabulary, Greek /ps/ continues the Proto-Indo-European sequence ps, bs, bʰs, kʷs, ɡʷs, and ɡʷʰs (the latter three only if not preceded by u or w). In most cases these occur across morpheme boundaries (in particular, masculine & feminine root nouns whose stem ends in a labial stop will all have a psi /ps/ in the nominative singular).

Most word-initial /ps/ in Greek appear to be from the Pre-Greek substrate though. The exact linguistic affiliation of this substrate is unknown, but an Afroasiatic affiliation is generally considered to be implausible. See Beekes for more information of Pre-Greek.

There may be some words with /ps/ in them in Greek that are borrowed from Afroasiatic sources, but these will be few in comparison to the other two sources.

Comment: At this point I'm also curious on why it ended up spelled as a single letter, though

Comment: that is probably worth a separate question

Comment: It can also continue a labiovelar plus s.

Comment: @TKR good point, I'll add that to the answer